# Email alert for grunt jshint output in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: build, azure-devops, grunt-contrib-jshint

I have grunt task for jshint. And in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online), I have configured grunt task to read my gruntfile.js.

I would like to configure **something** in Team Services that my build configuration should send out email to team with all jsHint errors. Another thing is, build result (success/fail) should not depend upon jsHint errors. All I am looking is how to sent out an email from Team Services with jsHint errors.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure, why is this downvoted now after almost 4 years. Could the person who downvoted it explain me why its downvoted so I will know and consider it when I ask new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the alert, there isn't any way to do this for now. The email notification for build only include the basic information: Build Status, Build Definition, Time and some summary information. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

To pass the build with jshint errors, you can add "--force" in grunt jshint task which will pass the task with warnings.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am trying it out on my end and will update here with my observations.